# Problem installing NVIDIA-Linux-x86-302.07.run in 12.04

Tags: nvidia

I have a catch 22 problem in trying to install this driver (NVIDIA-Linux-x86-302.07.run) to set my screen to its native resolution of 1280x1024 (hpL1906).

Problem is that in order to install this driver, I need to stop the XServer but when I do this (`sudo service lightdm stop`), my screen goes blank and displays the message -

> Out of Range 1280X1024 need to reset

(or something similar) - and I can go no further.

So, I cannot install NVIDIA-Linux-x86-302.07.run without stopping lightdm but when I do so, I can no longer see anything on the screen or go further to install the driver that would let me adjust the resolution. Any advice on getting out of this loop would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Nvidia drivers through Ubuntu Software Center or Jockey (Aditional Drivers). No need to install the .sh from NVIDIA.

Comment: Hi LnxSlck, did not want to cover material in other posts so did not give the history, but the Additional Drivers installed through Jockey were the cause of the initial problem resulting in a screen resolution so low (800x600) that the important icons were obscured and the program unworkable.  It was only when the NVIDIA Driver was removed and the generic Linux/Ubuntu Driver took over that the program has become workable with resolution at 1024x768. The New Driver (NVIDIA-Linux-x86-302.07.run) does not appear as an option in Jockey.  Will see how I go from Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question entirely, but I think you can switch to a text-based instance of Ubuntu, stop the X Server and then install the package from there.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a text-based environment (<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> are text-based).
2. Stop the X Server with `sudo service lightdm stop`.
3. Install your package.
4. Restart the X Server with `sudo service lightdm restart`.
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to the default graphical instance.

I'm kind of newbie in Ubuntu. I hope my answer helps.

Comment: This I have tried, the Ctrl+Alt+F1 command along with others in this series just blacks out the screen and displays the message - Out of Range 1280X1024 need to reset (or something similar) - and I can go no further without a Restart (Ctrl+Alt+Del).